# Write to fonts (OTF & TTF) Property details with PHP

Tags: php, fonts, truetype, opentype

I am trying to write specific details into the Properties > Details of .otf and .ttf files.

The idea behind this is to be able to insert specific license key information in the font file on download. This way when a font gets shared, we can view the license key.

I know this is easier with phyton, but ideally, we would like to do this with PHP, if at all possible.

Comment: on a technical note, "properties > details" is not a thing. The OpenType spec has clear and specific names for the metadata tables, and the fields in those tables, so if you're talking about a license, you're talking about updating the license string in the Name table. PHP has no great font libraries available, and updating the License field (or any value) requires multiple checksum recomputations and updates as well, so I'd strongly recommend to use the python FontTools library for this, which is an industry-trusted (open source) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib?

By the way, this operation is risky, because if you use a font parser / exporter library that is not complete you could loose some informations from the original font. So you need to check if the library you're using is supporting the features
included in the font.

That's why Python libraries, like [FontTools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) are recommended.